# Move tables and figures to the end of a section/chapter

Tags: floats

I am looking for a way to customize the position of the figures/tables of my document.
Is there a way to move the figures/tables to the end of each section of the document?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One posibility is to us a stack-like system.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% Define a new stack by letting it to \@empty
\newcommand\newStack[1]{\global\let#1\@empty}
% add element to stack (top): \addStack{<stack>}{<element>}
\newcommand\addStack[2]{\def\ele@ment{{#2} }\xdef#1{\ele@ment #1}}
% add element to stack (bottom) \revaddStack{<stack>}{<element>}
\newcommand\revaddStack[2]{\def\ele@ment{{#2} }\xdef#1{#1 \ele@ment}}

% remove from stack
\long\def\pop@#1 #2\@nil#3{\def\popedStackElement{#1}%
  \def#3{#2}}% remaining list
% stack name #1
\newcommand\popStack[1]{\let\popedStackElement\@empty%
\ifx #1\@empty\message{LaTeX warning: you are trying to remove an element from the empty stack \noexpand#1 on input line \the\inputlineno}\else\expandafter\pop@#1\@nil#1\fi}
% whipe stack
\newcommand\cleanStack[1]{\global\let#1\@empty}
\makeatother
```

Depending on how complicate your floats are it is probably a good idea to put them in one file each and append them with something like

```
\newcommand{\printfloats}{\begingroup%
  \def\do##1{\input{##1}}%
    \dolistloop{\myfloatsattheend}%
  \endgroup}
```

which would require something like

```
\newStack{\myfloatsattheend}

[some text]

\revaddstack{\myfloatsattheend}{<floatsfilename1>}

[some text]

\revaddstack{\myfloatsattheend}{<floatsfilename2>}
```

and at the end of the section

```
\printfloats
\cleanStack{\myfloatsattheend}
```